# Rails 3 - gem for storing and tracking changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

What is a good way for me to store and track revisions when using rails 3.0.9?

Comment: What do you mean by store and track register changes?

Comment: If I add a new register to the database or update a previous one, I want to know what model was, the action (create, update, delete, etc.), who made the change, when, and how the attributes had changed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Model history can be tracked with gems like [acts_as_versioned](https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned), [vestal_versions](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions), [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail), etc.

If you're not talking about model versioning, please provide details.